# How can I write session variable from model/table in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, session

I am trying to assign a session variable based on a model or database table on my Django site.  In other words, on the first use, I want the user to select a county from a dropdown list and write the name of that county or pk to a session variable.  From therek, that data gets pulled into context_processor before hitting the template.  Right now, the error I'm getting is

(1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'county_id'")

I'm not sure if it is trying to write multiple entries into the database, but I don't really want anything databased as you would other data.  I just want a session variable stored.  I am sure my problem is my view, but I can't seem to get it right.  In case you couldn't tell, I'm pretty new at this.

I have a model.py defined that accesses another table of counties.

```
class NonUserCounty(models.Mdel):
county = models.ForeignKey(County)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.county
```

I have defined a form.py

```
class NonUserCountyForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = NonUserCounty
```

And a views.py

```
def Welcome(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NonUserCountyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        mycounty = form.cleaned_data['county']
        request.session['mycounty'] = mycounty
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = NonUserCountyForm()  
    context = {'form': form}    
    return render_to_response('welcome.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

A Context processor

```
def mynews(request):        
now = datetime.now()
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    if not "mycounty" in request.GET:
        MyNews = News
        county = County 
    else:   
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/welcome/')            

else:       
    user = request.user.get_profile()
    county = user.county.all()
    MyNews = News
```

And my template....

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}


<p><input type="submit" alt="register" value="Sign Up" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling `form.save()` if you don't want to save anything in the database? Just remove that line and it should work.

Comment: When I removed 'form.save()', it throws no errors, but it doesn't seem to actually save the session data.  Is there a save method I need use for a session variable?

Comment: No, that should be enough (since you're using a top-level name, rather than modifying a value in a sub-dictionary). Where are you checking the changed value?

Comment: The template level.  As you can see, it should redirect to a different page if the variable is set, but it fails to do so.  I attempted to pull the variable into the welcome.html template, but the variable is not showing up.

Comment: You mean in that context processor? There are quite a few serious problems with that code. Firstly you seem to be checking request.GET rather than request.session, and anyway you can't redirect from a context processor. (I'll leave aside the strange assignments to variables that are not used.)

Comment: Ha! figures. This is my first Django site.  My problem that keeps arising is that I need all the variables available on all my pages.  If I put them somewhere else, it fails to display them where I need.  Where

Comment: Scatch my previous comment. The unused variables are used, I just didn't post the complete context processor. No matter what happens, I need that variable set or else I need my site to go to the welcome screen.  Should I redirect at the template level?  Is there a better way to check to be sure that the session variable is assigned?  Thanks for your help on this btw!